# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed error while trying to create a facebook app

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create a small facebook application. In my php file, I have written code to just display my name and to get my friend's list. This is my code:

```
 <?php

   echo "<p>Hello, <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\"></fb:name>!</p>";
   echo "<p>Friends:";
   $friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_get();
   $friends = array_slice($friends, 0, 25);
   foreach ($friends as $friend) {
      echo "<br>$friend";
   }
    echo "</p>";
 ?>
```

This is the output I get:

```
Hello, Angeline Aarthi!

Friends:

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
No such host is known. in C:\Documents and Settings\256148\My Documents\ide\xampplite\htdocs\facebookApp\facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 1755

Warning: fopen(http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php) [function.fopen]: 
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
No such host is known. in C:\Documents and Settings\256148\My Documents\ide\xampplite\htdocs\facebookApp\facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 1755

Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\Documents and Settings\256148\My Documents\ide\xampplite\htdocs\facebookApp\index.php on line 29

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Documents and Settings\256148\My Documents\ide\xampplite\htdocs\facebookApp\index.php on line 30
```

Please someone help me resolve my errors.

Comment: The problem was due to incorrect extension path in the php.ini fiel. Due to that, the necessary dll files weren't loaded. So I get the error msg. Now it is resolved.

Comment: I'm having a similiar problem, can you please specify which necessary dll weren't being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `allow_url_fopen` flag to `1` in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

In your C-Panel there is an option to use Hotlink protection, i think currently it's in enable, you need to disable this to work external link access via.,fopen() and file_get_contents() etc.

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.